# I am using free hosting for my practice , i am facing now the problem of HTTP ERROR 500 and

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I am using free hosting for my practice , i am facing now the problem of HTTP ERROR 500 and
503
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later!
when i goes to edit website it show 503

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later!
I have check resources usage > inodes that is also 6% used and there is no tarffic available on my website
help me to solve and re-fix it

Comment: It sounds possible that your free hosting service is restricting your use of your site, or that they put too many users on too few machines. 503, especially, is a sign of server overload.